# Retrieve value TR in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Goal:
Retrieve the value "2TR" from "MARSSTANDGATA132TR" in javascript.
Need to retrieve the index number of number 2.

Problem:
Just don't know what is the right syntax to do it?

Info:
*The value "TR" is always in the end of the word.
*The number "2" of "TR" is always changing. it is only a single number, no two or 3 numbers.
*The address and address number is always changing.
*When you execute the regex code and it cannot find the TR in the end of the word, then you cannot retrieve the requested result.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var str = "MARSSTANDGATA132TR"; 
    var n = str.search("TR");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Test</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Thank you!

Comment: you are looking for regex or even exploding the string and getting the last 3rd index should work

Comment: "in the end of the word" or at the end of the *string*?

Comment: End of the string

Comment: Given that `TR` is always at the end of the string, and the number which in this case is `2` is always one digit, then I guess the index of number `2` is `str.length - 3`

Comment: @Onheiron: Yes, but first there must be a check for `TR` at the end of the string.

Comment: Then use `string.endsWith()`:https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_endswith.asp

Comment: @Onheiron: The Justinas's answer shows a better option with `slice` (supported by all browsers).

Answer (score 2):

Since TR is always at the end of sting, than you do not need to use regex here.

Take last two symbols, check if it's TR, if yes - take third symbol from the end of string - else - do error processing:

```js
var str = "MARSSTANDGATA132TR";

if (str.slice(-2) == 'TR') {
  console.log(''+str.slice(-3, -2) + ' and index is ' + (str.length - 3));
} else {
  console.log('no TR');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to use the index instead to find correct tr and num idx:

```
let str = "MARSSTANDGATA132TR"; 
let tr = str.search("TR"), numIdx;

if (tr !== -1) {
  numIdx = str[tr -1];      
  tr = str.substr(tr, tr + 1);
} else {
  alert('no TR');
}
console.log(tr);
console.log(numIdx)
```

or in case that the string contains multiple TRs, then you want to make sure that its really the correct one.

```
let str = "MARSS**TR**ANDGATA132**TR**"; 
let trIdx = 0, tr, numIdx;

let findTrIdx = (str) => {
  let tmpIdx = str.search('TR');
  if (!parseInt(str[tmpIdx - 1])) {
    let newStr = str.substr(tmpIdx + 2, str.length -1);
    tmpIdx = tmpIdx + 2;
    findTrIdx(newStr);
  } 
  trIdx += tmpIdx;
  return trIdx;
}

trIdx = findTrIdx(str);

if (trIdx !== -1) {
    numIdx = str[trIdx -1];
  tr = str.substr(trIdx, trIdx + 1);
} else {
    alert('no TR');
}
console.log(tr);
console.log(numIdx)
```